# Syntax for using onSelect with jQuery's datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onselect

Simple enough, I hope. I'm trying to get a div to fadeIn when I click on a date in jQuery's datepicker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../datepicker/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../datepicker/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#foo').fadeIn();
        });
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<p>Choose a date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>

<div id="foo">FOO</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your code has an extra parentheses and a semi-colon, see the comment on the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#foo').fadeIn();
        }); // <-- HERE, it should be just }
    });
});
```

This is the correct code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $('#foo').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

2. There is no need to attach the `datepicker()` twice to the same element, you just assign it once, with the appropriate parameters, hence why I removed the extra `$('#datepicker').datepicker()`.

3. You should hide the element in order for it to remain hidden until you fade it in. Use this CSS:

```css
#foo{
    display: none;
}
```

[Check a demo here »](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/puxkZ/)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the head's up on the style.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors on your javascript and another problem is that you can't fadeIn() an element which is visible: you have to hide it before.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').hide();
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $('#foo').fadeIn();
        }
    });

    });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vH4HV/1/